# Curl (35) SSL connect error

Tags: ssl, curl, https, localhost

I am trying to run cURL in the command line. I run it to connect to a website hosted on the same server I am running the command. It is just a GET command to a local HTTPS site.

When I run the command, I get the error "curl: (35) SSL connect error". The command used to work, but it has recently stopped. I did just update my SSL certificates and the Apache settings for the SSL Protocol and CipherSuite. Could that be my issue?

What can I do to solve this and be able to connect with cURL? I can open the site in the browser with no issues.

I am running CentOS 6 with cURL 7.19.7.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I needed updated the ca-certificates package (yum update ca-certificates.noarch). Now everything seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!